# quicksort divide-and-conquer returns incorrect partial answer

Tags: python, debugging, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

My program does not return the correct question in the end but it shows correct ones in the intermediate results. I needs help, thanks.

Output sample:

```
sort begin: A,start,end [3, 5, 2, 1, 7, 6, 8, 4] 0 7

sort begin: A,start,end [2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 4] 0 1

sort begin: A,start,end [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 4] 3 7

sort begin: A,start,end [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7] 3 3

sort begin: A,start,end [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7] 5 7

sort begin: A,start,end [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7] 5 4

sort begin: A,start,end [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7] 6 7

####################################################


final result [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7]
```

My code:

```
def qSort(A,start,end):
    print "sort begin: A,start,end",A,start,end
    if start >= end:
        return A
    elif end == start + 1:
        if A[start] > A[end]:
            A[start],A[end] = A[end],A[start]
        return A
    else:
        i = start + 1
        j = i
        p = A[start]
        while j < end:
            j = j + 1
            if p > A[j]:
                A[i],A[j] = A[j],A[i]
                i = i + 1
        A = A[0:start] + A[start+1:i]+ [p] + A[i:end+1]

        qSort(A,start,i-2)
        qSort(A,i,end)
        return A

print "###################"
myarray = [3,5,2,1,7,6,8,4]

result = qSort(myarray,0,7)
print "final result",result
```

Comment: One line quicksort `qsort1 = lambda lst : lst if len(lst) <= 1 else qsort1([i for i in lst[1:] if i < lst[0]]) + [lst[0]] + qsort1([i for i in lst[1:] if i >= lst[0]])` copied from truppo's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228181/the-zen-of-python

Comment: I can't beat it ...... just started to use python T_T ...... still don't know what's wrong with my code ... or it must be two portion of code. a recursive one and a summary one?

Comment: These may help you find your problem! http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_(Python)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my lack luster comments. I reviewed your code and realized it was correct! You have one minor coding mistake which I will point out and then explain. In your `else` block you currently have:

```
else:
    # Bunch of correct stuff
    # ...  
    # Stuff that is ALMOST correct
    qSort(A,start,i-2)
    qSort(A,i,end)
    return A
```

you need to change this to:

```
else:
    # Bunch of correct stuff
    # ...  
    # Stuff that is definitely correct
    A = qSort(A,start,i-2)
    A = qSort(A,i,end)
    return A
```

Without going too deeply into this, your function does not discriminate between list references and newly created lists. If you put `print A` in you `elif` block right before `return A` you will notice that on the final iteration, your sort, as is, does everything correctly, and produces the correct list!

Unfortunately, the call that produced this change was one of the lines I've mentioned above which calls the sort but doesn't store the resulting list returned by the recursive function call!

My simple change just takes the modified list returned from secondary function calls to qSort and reassigns the variable A.

Weirdly, this behavior actually worked ok for you sometimes for reasons I cannot fully explain (like the first time you enter your `elif' block which does the right thing and modifies the list correctly). I am sure someone smarter than I surely can explain the odd behavior.

Alternatively, you could come up with a simple way to count recursion depth (number of times your function calls itself) and print that out while debugging with some breakpoints in your favorite IDE.

Heres how you could do that with global variables:

```
recursion_depth = -1

def qSort(A,start,end):
    global recursion_depth
    recursion_depth += 1
    print "sort begin: A,start,end,level",A,start,end,recursion_depth
    # bunch of code edited out for brevity
    # ...

result = qSort(myarray,0,7)
print "final result",result
```

Comment: I tried your update but it failed like when you increase your inputs to bigger array (my previous case is just luck). and here is some debug information. A = qsort(a,start,i-2) index error: list index out of range ... sorry stackoverflow does not allow my paste ...

Comment: can you paste the test case that failed?